# iOS : Storing a table of rows and columns

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Am just mulling over what's the best way i.e. data structure to store a data that has several rows and columns. Shoudl I store it as :
1. an array of arrays?
2. NSDictionary?

or is there any grid-like data structure in iOS where I can easily  fetch any row/column with ease from the data structure? For example, I must be able to fetch the value in 3rd column in row 5. Currently, say, I store each row as an array and the store these arrays in another array (so an array of arrays, say), then to fetch the value in column 3 in row 5, I need to fetch the 5th row in the array of arrays, and then in the resulting array, I need to fetch the 3rd object. Is there a better way to do this? Thoughts please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then to fetch the value in column 3 in row 5, I need to fetch the 5th
>   row in the array of arrays, and then in the resulting array, I need to
>   fetch the 3rd object. Is there a better way to do this?

An array of arrays is fine for the implementation, and the collection subscripting that was recently added to Objective-C makes this easier -- you can use an expression like

```
NSString *s = myData[m][n];
```

to get the string at the `n`th column of the `m`th row.

That said, it may still be a good idea to create a separate class for your data structure, so that the rest of your code is protected from needing to know about how the data is stored. That would also simplify the process of changing the implementation from, say, an array of arrays to a SQLite table or something else.

Your data storage class doesn't need to be fancy or complicated. Here's a first pass:

```
@interface DataTable

- (id)objectAtRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column;
- (void)setObjectAtRow:(NSInteger)row column:(NSInteger)column;

@end
```

I'm sure you can see how to implement those in terms of an array of arrays. You'll have to do a little work to add rows and/or columns when the caller tries to set a value outside the current bounds. You might also want to add support for things like [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html) and writing to and reading from [property lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/CreatePropListProgram/CreatePropListProgram.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH5-SW4), but that can come later.

Comment: That's a pretty wonderful way, Caleb! Can you please elaborate on the fast enumeration, and on reading & writing to property lists please? Am not sure I got that.

Comment: @Jean I've added a couple links to help, but I only meant that fast enumeration and property lists are features that you might like to have in a data collection class. For example, it could be handy to read or write an entire `DataTable` from/to a file in one step, and it'll be trivial to implement using NSArray's support for property lists, but don't worry about that stuff until you find you need it.

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways of doing it, but there's nothing wrong with the method you are using. You could use an NSDictionary with a key of type NSIndexPath, for example, or even a string key of the form "row,col", but I don't see any advantage in those except for sparse matrices.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an array of arrays, as you're doing, or an array of dictionaries. Either is fine, and I don't think there's any preference for one over the other. It all depends on which way is most convenient for you to set up the data structure in the first place. Accessing the data for the table view is equally easy using either method.